# Copy value of cell (A) to another cell (B) based on cell (C)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to write a Google Apps Script that states the following:

When Column 4 is "Action", then copy the value in Column 2 to Column 9. So far I have this:

```
function autoAssign() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var r = s.getActiveRange();
 var c = s.getActiveCell()
 var row = r.getRow();

 if(s.getName() == "New Requests" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Action") { 
s.getRange(row,2).copyTo(ss.getRange(row,9)) ; 
 }
 }
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It doesn't work. I am curious if anyone sees the problem with it. Or has another script that does work.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it. Can you provide more details about `It doesn't work`? Are you getting any error? Are you executing this from the editor?